# Javascript failing to load images

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas

I'm currently getting familiar with HTML 5 and Javascript and am currently trying to load and draw images to a HTML 5 canvas with Javascript.
Here's the HTML code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Adam Leung</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>pegGame</h1>
        <canvas id="mainCanvas" onload="" onclick="test()" width="800" height="480"></canvas>
        <a><br>by: Adam Leung</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the javascript code:

```
function test(){
    var mainCanvas = document.getElementById("mainCanvas");
    var logoImage = new Image();
    logoImage.src = "img/gameLogo.png";
    alert(logoImage.width);
    mainCanvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(logoImage, 0, 0);
}
```

and here is the file structure:

```
/Site Root
   -/css
      -style.css
   -/img
      -gameLogo.png
   -/js
      -main.js
-index.html
```

gameLogo.png is just a image that's 300px by 300px. I am lead to believe that when I load the index.html and click inside the canvas, it should print "300" in a popup and draw gameLogo.png onto the canvas. When I do click the canvas, a popup comes up with "0" and no image draws, what's going on?
(Edit: I am testing in the latest version of Chrome)

Much thanks.

Comment: do you see your alert with width of image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add an onload handler to the image and you should be good to go:

```
function test(){
    var mainCanvas = document.getElementById("mainCanvas");
    var logoImage = new Image();

    logoImage.onload = loadingDone;      // here before setting src

    logoImage.src = "img/gameLogo.png";

    function loadingDone() {             // gets called when done
        alert(logoImage.width);
        mainCanvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(logoImage, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

Image loading is asynchronous so you need to use callbacks. If not the code will just continue and try to draw the image before it has finished loading (which will turn out as a blank image).

Also use a callback for errors (`onerror`).

Answer (score 1):

The `drawImage()` method requires an image object. Create an image and wait for it to load before calling `drawImage()`.  Use `onload` method.

something like,

```
  var imageObj = new Image();
  imageObj.onload = function() {
    context.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 50);
  };
  imageObj.src = '../img/gameLogo.png';
```

Comment: @vladkras `If you try to call drawImage() before the image has finished loading, it won't do anything (or, in older browsers, may even throw an exception).` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Canvas_tutorial/Using_images)

Comment: [html5canvastutorials.com](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-images/)?